# When I typed 'python manage.py shell' , I am getting this stuff.Please explain what is this?

Tags: python, django

```
E:\myenv\mydjango1\mysite>python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.


In [2]: 

In [4]:
```

Comment: You're in an iPython interpreter. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: Do you know what a shell is?

Comment: For everyone downvoting I think it's an honest question though maybe the title could be phrased better. If you've never seen IPython before it wouldn't be immediately obvious what to do with it.

Comment: @Iguananaut "not immediately obvious" does not translate to immediately writing an SO question. The shell even says that it's ipython

Comment: Sure it does. Honestly there are so many worse questions along the lines of "I can't figure out what's wrong with my code" that are far less useful.

Comment: @Iguananaut that doesn't mean that that thought process should be supported. You're benchmarking degrees of incorrectness, not the type of content that should be encouraged. People should be expected to do at least minimal research on their issues

Comment: Sorry, nope. It's a fair beginner question. If I've never programmed before that IPython prompt looks like line noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#shell) `manage.py shell` opens a Python interpreter to do stuff with your code interactively. If you have an enhanced interpreter like IPython or bpython it will tend to use that by default. What you posted is just the standard IPython prompt, which is more powerful that the default interactive prompt you get when you run just `python`. For example, you can run normal shell commands at the IPython prompt, such as `ls` and `cd`.

Comment: Actually I want to go into Python shell then which command I have to use instead of 'python manage.py shell'.

Comment: As opposed to just `python` or `ipython`? I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```
python manage.py shell
```

You get a python interpreter. Try it out. type in:

```
print("hello world")
```

and press enter. Everything works like in a normal python interpreter. Except, there's a benefit to doing it like this, which is that your Django application will be initiated, so you can interact directly with with it. So, for example, let's say that you have an app called "application", and a model called "Blog", then, you could type something like this:

```
from application.models import Blog
for blog in Blog.objects.all():
    print(blog)
```

So usually you would use the shell when you need to interact with your Django project, and you need all the Django initialisation stuff to have run (try interacting with the Django db api from a normal python script... won't work).

Comment: I want to verify my postgresql connection from shell then how can i do it?